# EC2インスタンス内からECRにログインできない

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, aws-ecr

EC2インスタンス内からECRへのログインのため、以下のコマンドでログインを試みました。
このEC2インスタンスのIAMRoleには[AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly]ポリシーを付与しています。

```
$(aws ecr get-login --region ap-northeast-1)
```

しかし以下のエラーメッセージが表示され、ログインは失敗します。

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'.
```

なぜログインに失敗するのでしょうか？

`$()` の中身のみのコマンド `aws ecr get-login --region ap-northeast-1` を叩くと、以下のようなレスポンスが返ってきます。

```
docker login -u AWS -p ********= -e none https://************.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker 17.06で`--email`/`-e`オプションは[廃止](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/143)されていますが、AWS CLIはデフォルトでは互換性のためにこれを出力しているそうです。

`aws ecr get-login`に`--no-include-email`オプションを付与することで-eオプションが[出力されなく](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html#options)なりますが、そもそも`get-login`は非推奨であり、[aws-cli v2で廃止](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/aws-cli-v2-ecr-get-login-password/)されました。`get-login-password`を使用してください。